# Can i handle multiplayer game and highest data in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Can i create multiplayer game in socket.IO.
i am try to lots of data handle in socket.IO. i am create highest multiplayer game like poker, black jack, Teen Patti. my question is can i create this type of game handle in socket.IO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely. Socket.io provides a nice layer of abstraction above regular websockets, and a feature you'll likely want to make use of is [rooms](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/).

Rooms let you bundle together several client connections into a virtual "room", meaning you can easily send messages within the room to all recipients.

Comment: Thanks for give Answer

Comment: @RadadiyaRavi If it answered your question, click the green check mark :)

Comment: yes but can i handle million of user in socket.io

Comment: @RadadiyaRavi it certainly seems that way, depending on your server architecture. check out [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708779/9063935), and google "scale up socket.io" for even more information. when scaling up in this sort (especially if you're using nodejs) how the language works under-the-hood is more important when scaling than the library (which is still important obv)